# Page link to the navigation bar with changing contents

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation

I found how to add a page link to the navigation bar, but it seems that I can put static contents in the page like if you want to change it, you have to do it by yourself if the panel admin.

What I want it's, for example, a link "new products" in the navigation bar and the page associated show the last 10 new products added and those products change while new products are add.

Is it possible to do something like that ? And how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a widget for that on the CMS Page editor 'Catalog New Product List' it will pull newly added products according to the parameters to give it

[image]

---

[image]